# Esquemas en SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Tengo una pregunta sencilla, pero que puede tener un poco de confusión para los que vamos empezando con SQLite.

Mi pregunta es si se pueden crear Schemas en SQLite o hay algo parecido?

Investigando en internet he encontrado que el Attach database me podría ayudar, pero me gustaría saber si de verdad cumpliria con lo que necesito, lo cual es crear varios esquemas para tener mas organizadas mis tablas.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta es que en SQLite no existe el concepto de Schema, propio de otras bases de datos.

El [concepto](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) de `attached` es distinto y se utiliza para acceder a objetos en bases de datos adjuntas.

La confusión suele venir debido a que en SQLite utiliza la palabra `schema` para la definición de una tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas, la respuesta corta es que "si", se pueden crear esquemas en sqlite.

Ahora bien, como para ver como se hace, lo mejor es que si quieres aprender sqlite te recomiendo apuntarte a un curso del mismo, hay varios por internet, o bien puedes mirar guías completas y la documentación oficial.

Pero te facilito un enlace para que puedas ver como empezar con esta tecnología:
http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/

En la anterior url, explican como formar un esquema sencillo y tu primera base de datos. Espero que te ayude.